# Type casting to trait. T as Config

Tags: generics

this is rust-based question.
In Substrate code, there are lots of type casting. For example,
for the BalanceOf type alias,

```
<<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance
```

How is it possible to cast generic type(T) to some trait(Config), which has no exact size on compile time?

Thank you

Comment: Monomorphisation. If you have 3 different impl of the trait then when you pass it to a function, three concrete functions taking those types will be created. (The alternative would be dyn objects where a virtual lookup table is used and there's only one copy of the final function.)

Comment: You will see this pattern often to make the code a bit more readable: `type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::EVM as EVM<AccountIdOf<T>>>::Balance;`

Comment: so... does T as config, type-casting..? or just simply bouding the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<T as Config>` is just a generic bound.

`type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`

Is just a type alias, because typing out the right side is just annoying, when  compared to `BalanceOf<T>`.

This kind of type alias appears when we are trying to extract a concrete associated type from some trait. In this case the `type Balance` is an associated type of `trait Currency`, and we want to easily access this type.

Comment: Thank you for the details, Shawn!